# 3Proxy with Rotating IP's

Tags: proxy, transparent-proxy

I want to configure a proxy which can rotate the IP's on session basis. Let me explain what I have done so far and what is exact requirement.

I installed 3 proxy configured it to listen on 10 Public interfaces which is working fine. But my requirement is if any user access the internet, IP which will go out should be changed for every new session. Lets say my prxy IP's are from 10.20.30.5-14. When an user opens google.com it will hit google webserver with 10.20.30.5 IP and now if same user opens up yahoo.com then, it should it with 10.20.30.6 or any ip b/w 6 to 14.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What benefit would it bring?

Comment: can you post your 3proxy config file somewhere? if you still have it 4 years later lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a load balancer to sit in front of your proxy and redirect users to the proper IP, 3 proxy alone will not do this.